# Accessing variable and functions in object oriented python - python

Tags: python, oop, variables, init

1. **How to I declare a default value in a python object?**

Without a python object it looks fine:

```
def obj(x={123:'a',456:'b'}):
    return x
fb = obj()
print fb
```

With a python object I get the following error:

```
def foobar():
    def __init__(self,x={123:'a',456:'b'}):
        self.x = x
    def getStuff(self,field):
        return x[field]
fb = foobar()
print fb.x

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testclass.py", line 9, in <module>
    print fb.x
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'x'
```

1. **How do I get the object to return the value of a variable in the object?**

With a python object, I got an error:

```
def foobar():
    def __init__(self,x={123:'a',456:'b'}):
        self.x = x
    def getStuff(self,field):
        return x[field]

fb2 = foobar({678:'c'})
print fb2.getStuff(678)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testclass.py", line 8, in <module>
    fb2 = foobar({678:'c'})
TypeError: foobar() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: [Don't use mutable default arguments.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't define a class, you defined a function with nested functions.

```
def foobar():
    def __init__(self,x={123:'a',456:'b'}):
        self.x = x
    def getStuff(self,field):
        return x[field]
```

Use `class` to define a class instead:

```
class foobar:
    def __init__(self,x={123:'a',456:'b'}):
        self.x = x
    def getStuff(self, field):
        return self.x[field]
```

Note that you need to refer to `self.x` in `getStuff()`.

Demo:

```
>>> class foobar:
...     def __init__(self,x={123:'a',456:'b'}):
...         self.x = x
...     def getStuff(self, field):
...         return self.x[field]
... 
>>> fb = foobar()
>>> print fb.x
{456: 'b', 123: 'a'}
```

Do note that using a mutable value for a function keyword argument default is generally *not* a good idea. Function arguments are defined *once*, and can lead to unexpected errors, as now all your classes share the same dictionary.

See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: Worth pointing out the mutable default argument issue as well.

Comment: Martijn is a fast typist! :D

Answer (score 1):

to define a class in python you have to use

```
    class classname(parentclass):
        def __init__():
            <insert code>
```

With your code you're declaring a method not a class

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
class foobar:
```

instead of

```
def foobar():
```