# Why __init__ in python fail

Tags: python, class, init

I'm using python2.7 to define a function like this

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    print 'args = ', args
    print 'kwargs = ', kwargs
    print '---------------------------------------'
```

and by calling foo(3), the output is as the following:

```
args =  (3,)
kwargs =  {}
```

which is desired.

But as for `__init__` function in a class in which the parameters are the same form as foo, I can't instantize the class Person by invoking `Person(3)`

```
def Person():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print args
        print kwargs
x = Person(3)
```

The output is

```
    x = Person(3)
TypeError: Person() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

That confused me a lot, have I missed something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing variable and functions in object oriented python - python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610378/accessing-variable-and-functions-in-object-oriented-python-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably meant to create a *class* instead of a *function*:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print args
        print kwargs
```

[`__init__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) is for classes :).

Comment: So, how can I use *args and **kwargs for the construct function of a class. I'm initially trying to overload the initialization function within a class but python doesn't support that feature. 
The desired calling is as the following:
a = Person(name="xxx")
b = Person(age=16)

Comment: @speedmancs: You do it exactly the way you had it in your code, except without accidentally using `def` where you meant `class`.

Comment: Thank you, I've really made this mistake:)

Comment: @speedmancs Don't worry, everyone makes mistakes every once in a while ;). Also, don't forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)!